# Проблема с импортом .sql файла в таблицу

Tags: mysql

У меня есть файл .sql на 565 запросов. Но возникает проблема его импорта.
.sql файл

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Хост: ~secret host~
-- Время создания: Июл 05 2021 г., 09:07
-- Версия сервера: 10.5.10-MariaDB-1:10.5.10+maria~focal
-- Версия PHP: 7.4.16

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- База данных: `default`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `main`
--

CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `realname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastlogin` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `y` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `z` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `world` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'world',
  `regdate` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `regip` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `yaw` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `pitch` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isLogged` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `hasSession` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `totp` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `main`
--

INSERT INTO `main` (`id`, `username`, `realname`, `password`, `ip`, `lastlogin`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `world`, `regdate`, `regip`, `yaw`, `pitch`, `email`, `isLogged`, `hasSession`, `totp`) VALUES
(1, 'nickname0', 'nickname0', 'password', 'ip', 1625417638755, 'regip', 1621279093622, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'world', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL),
(2, 'nickname1', 'nickname1', 'password', 'ip', 1624986506222, 'regip', 1621319622324, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'world', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1, NULL),
(3, 'nickname2', 'nickname2', 'password', 'ip', 1623681067264, 'regip', 1621321268134, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'world', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1, NULL),
[~куча однородных строк спустя~]
(563, 'nickname562', 'nickname562', 'password', 'ip', 1625429997019, 'regip', 1625429045740, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'world', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL),
(564, 'nickname563', 'nickname563', 'password', 'ip', 1625453988780, 'regip', 1625453883257, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'world', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL),
(565, 'nickname564', 'nickname564', 'password', 'ip', 1625462276338, 'regip', 1625462248786, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'world', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `main`
--
ALTER TABLE `main`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `main`
--
ALTER TABLE `main`
  MODIFY `id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Ошибка:

```
Найдено 19 ошибок при анализе.

Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`id`" at position 1019)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`username`" at position 1025)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`realname`" at position 1037)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`password`" at position 1049)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`ip`" at position 1061)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`lastlogin`" at position 1067)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`x`" at position 1080)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`y`" at position 1085)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`z`" at position 1090)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`world`" at position 1095)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`regdate`" at position 1104)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`regip`" at position 1115)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`yaw`" at position 1124)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`pitch`" at position 1131)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`email`" at position 1140)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`isLogged`" at position 1149)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`hasSession`" at position 1161)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`totp`" at position 1175)
Неизвестный оператор. (near "VALUES" at position 1183)

#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'INSERT INTO `authme` (`id`, `username`, `realname`, `password`, `ip`, `lastlo...' на строке 36
```

P. S. Все мои попытки исправить это оказались тщетными.

Comment: Вы после `ENGINE=InnoDB` забыли поставить точку с запятой

Comment: М-да... Такую тупую ошибку допустил и убил на нее полдня... Спасибо, что подсказали, все заработало.